# Sort table with numbers and connected numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I try to sort my table with tha values from `Column E`

The Problem is that this Column contains the following data:

```
 10
 9
 3, 4, 5
 1
 7, 8
 2
 6
```

And I need to sort is like:

```
 1
 2
 3, 4, 5
 6
 7, 8
 9
 10
```

With the normal sort function I got only this result:

```
 1
 2
 6
 9
 10
 3, 4, 5
 7, 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an extra column that extracts the first value from the comma separated values then sort by that column. Try the formula below:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",",E1,1)), LEFT(E1, SEARCH(",",E1,1)-1), E1)
```